# The whole page does not load when trying to request via session.get() Python, requests

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get data from one website, but the problem is that there is dynamic data loading. So when I try to make a request for requests
`session.get(url)`
I only get the first 5 listings.
I looked at what files are loaded when I scroll down and found the collect file. It sends a POST request to a third-party url of the form https://url/v1/collect, and there are headers like this

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en;q=0.9
Content-Length: **622**
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: url
Referer: url
Sec-Ch-Ua: ...
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: ...
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: ...
```

So I see that when I scroll down, the Content-Length header changes - it takes the values 622 or 927. Maybe this is what is requesting the additional data? But when I tried to send a POST request to this url I got a connection error.

I also tried using `requests_html`, method render(wait=3, sleep=2, ) but it gave the same results.
I don't want to use selenium, it's a big resource hog.
If there are alternative ways to solve with requests, please advise!
Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: Of course, https://www.milanuncios.com/